# Delete divs by 2 classes and node attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Imagine that we have some divs like that

```
<div class="row chapter" node="1">Chapter 1</div>
<div class="row section" node="1">Section 1</div>
```

Ajax accepts array of nodes that must be deleted. I got few questions about this

1) I'm using following function

```
                $.each(result['nodes'], function(column, node)){
                   $(".row."+column).slideUp("slow").remove();
                }
```

I can't figure out how to delete by 2 classes and node atribute. How to do that?

2) AFAIK $.each function deletes one by one. Is it possible to delete all at once?
3) How to deal with validation issues? I mean,

Comment: @Joseph `result['nodes']` is php side Ajax response that looks like {"chapter": 1, "section":1}

Comment: Offtopic: do you see the slideUp happen? Cause your elements are removed before any slideUp comes to a callback `.slideUp("slow").remove();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since an object only has key-value pairs, in order to handle two classes and one attribute, you'll have to change the structure of your JSON.  I suggest changing it to [{"class1":"foo","class2":"bar","node":1}].  With that format, this will work to collect the nodes:

```
$($.map(result['nodes'], function(o) {
    return "."+o.class1+"."+o.class2+"[node="+o.node+"]";
}).join(","))
```

As Joseph stated, your original code will remove the nodes too soon, so you'll need to put the `remove()` in a parameter to `slideUp()`:

```
$($.map(result['nodes'], function(o) {
    return "."+o.class1+"."+o.class2+"[node="+o.node+"]";
}).join(",")).slideUp("slow", function() {
    $(this).remove()
});
```

Sample jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tSu8z/

Note that there's really no "one by one" vs. "all at once" distinction.  With the code above, jQuery gets the order to slide the nodes up all at once, but internally it will iterate through the nodes.  Likewise, the nodes will most likely all appear to be deleted simultaneously, but jQuery is actually iterating through them.  The only requirement for it to look simultaneous is for `slideUp` to be asynchronous, which it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect the selectors using an array, join them and use remove all at once.

```
var toRemove = [];

$.each(result['nodes'], function(index, value){
    toRemove.push('.row.'+index+'[node='+value+']');
}

//$('.row.chapter[node=1], .row.section[node=1]')
$(toRemove.join(',')).slideUp("slow",function(){
    $(this).remove()
});
```

Comment: But result['nodes'] is already json. Can we do it without collecting into second array `toRemove`? How to deal with deleting with 3 parameters? I mean `class1`, `class2` and `node`?

Comment: @epic_syntax updated the answer. now includes node attribute.

Comment: Node is seperate attribute like `node="2"`

Comment: @epic_syntax you should distinguish which keys are classes, and which are attributes

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10831/discussion-between-epic-syntax-and-joseph)

Comment: @epic_syntax remove the extra closing parenthesis after `value` at the first error line