# How to get work live click function only inside exact div

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, jquery-events

Let's say we have divs with class `.row`.

Currently my live click function looks like that:

```
$(".row").live('click',function(event) {
```

What I want to do is to apply this function only to those divs, which are located inside exact div with class `data`. I mean

```
<div class="row">!don't apply!</div>
<div class="data">
   <div class="row">apply1!</div>
   <div class="row">apply2!</div>
</div>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: FYI, `live` is deprecated. You should use `delegate` or `on` for jQuery 1.7+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery's `.on()`

```
$('.data').on('click', '.row', function(){
  // function stuff
});
```

If the `.data` is loaded asynchronously too, you can go a "step further"

```
$('body').on('click', '.data .row', function(){
  // function stuff
});
```

Just replace `'body'` with your wrap selector...

Comment: HTML dynamically changes by Ajax. So I'm using live. Please take a look at this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427570/delete-divs-by-2-classes-and-node-attribute

Comment: If `.data` is loaded via AJAX too, check this edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".data > .row").live('click',function(event) {

});
```

But Try to avoid `live()` instead use like following:

```
$('.data').on('click', '.row', function() {

});
```

Or you can use `delegate()`

```
$(".data").delegate(".row", "click", function(){

});
```

Comment: Thx very much for your answer, sir. HTML dynamically changes by Ajax. So I'm using live. Please take a look at this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427570/delete-divs-by-2-classes-and-node-attribute

Answer (score 1):

You could be a bit more specific with your selector i.e.

```
$(".data > .row").live('click',function(event) {...
```

Comment: Please take a look at this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427570/delete-divs-by-2-classes-and-node-attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.data > .row').live('click',function(event) {
```

There you go.

The CSS selector > only picks "true" children. No grandchildren allowed.

[And do use on() since live() isn't encouraged any longer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042576#answers-header)

Comment: No, don't use `div.data` instead of `.data`.

Comment: Check this answer to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9181607/910868

Comment: Please take a look at this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427570/delete-divs-by-2-classes-and-node-attribute

Comment: I find it easier to work with 'div.class' then '.class' because that helps me have a better overlook of what I'm working with.

Comment: I'd consider using comments then... The performance diff is quite large.

Comment: Yeah I suppose... I use div.class in css, so I simply find it logical to use it in jQuery aswell. Can't really see myself writing `<!--div-->$('.class');` though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.data > .row').live('click',function(event) {
```